# Различие в AddTransient c фабрикой или без в dotnet core 3

Tags: .net-core, di

Есть класс

```
public class LongRunningStatus: IRunningStatus
{
    #region Implementation of IRunningStatus

    public LongRunningStatus()
    {
        Status = "Constructor";
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string Status { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

В методе `ConfigureServices` добавляю его так:

```
services.AddTransient<IRunningStatus, LongRunningStatus>();
```

В итоге, в методе контроллера

```
public ActionResult<string> Status([FromServices] IRunningStatus rs)
```

Я каждый раз получаю экземпляр с "`Constructor`".

Если же я, в конструкторе класса Start создаю экземпляр `IRunningStatus`, и потом присваиваю его

```
services.AddTransient<IRunningStatus, LongRunningStatus>(x => _runningStatus);
```

То данный сервис начинает вести себя так, словно он добавлен методом `AddSingleton`.
Т.е. конструктор вызывается всего один раз. Причём я могу менять значение поля `Status` и изменения будут видны в другом контроллере.

Такое поведение меня немного смущает. Так и должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [определения](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddTransient__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) `AddTransient`:

> public static IServiceCollection AddTransient(this IServiceCollection services, Func implementationFactory) where TService : class;
>   Adds a transient service of the type specified in TService with an implementation type specified in TImplementation to the specified IServiceCollection.

видно, что метод принимает в качестве параметра делегат, возвращающий нужный инстанс.

Ты передаёшь `x => _runningStatus`, который всегда возвращает один и тот же объект.
Так что да, так и должно быть.